# margin-left (set in percentage) shrinking with each element in Chrome (not in Firefox)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/6quT7/ so you can see how when viewed in Chrome every margin-left is becoming smaller, while viewed in Firefox margin-left is same dimensions for each element

Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="group">
<div class="group_unit_first_child">
    <p>Hermelin</p>
</div>
<div class="group_unit color_green">
    <p>2</p>
</div>
<div class="group_unit color_blue">
    <p>2</p>
</div>
<div class="group_unit color_white">
    <p>8</p>
</div>
<div class="group_unit color_orange">
    <p>2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is CSS:

```
.group_unit_first_child {
height: 100%;
width: 40.1%;
float: left;
background-color: #4e4e4e;
border-radius: 8px;
display: table;
}

.group_unit {
height: 100%;
width: 12.64%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
background-color: #4e4e4e;
border-radius: 8px;
margin-left: 0.96%;
display: table;

}
```

Is there any fix for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display: table;` from `.group_unit` should work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6quT7/1/)

Comment: Yes it works, but i have used
    display: table;
for the group_unit and 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
for the group_unit p

so i can center text vertically .. do you have any explanation or any other advice for why is this happening so i can try to find out some solution and keep vertical aligning 
thanks

Comment: you can just use margin-top to vertically center the group_unit p

Comment: True but whole website is scalable - made with percentages, and `margin-top` is tricky in percentages because it depends of width of the element with that margin - meaning if text is longer `margin-top` would be bigger, so that option is not applicable for me

Comment: So finally i gave up centering with above mentioned technique, and your advice on removing `display: table` was solution. Thanks for quick and helpful response!!

Answer (score 1):

I changed the display position from table to block and it works for me. Do you really need that `display:table` property?

Comment: I am using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` `vertical-align: middle;`to vertically center text inside that element

Comment: So finally i gave up centering with above mentioned technique, and your solution helped. Thanks for quick and helpful response!!